# $.connection is undefined when opening in new tab or new browser SignalR with SqlDependency

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, signalr, sqldependency

I created an mvc application and implement SignalR notification functions with SqlDependency it is working in single browser and single tab if i open it in new tab or new browser it's through error $.connection is undefined.
And i found that ~/signalr/hubs is load only home page and not load on other forms.

My code is:
Reference Jquery

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast notifications.
    notifications.client.updateNotifications = function () {
        getAllNotifications()
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        getAllNotifications();
    });
});

function getAllNotifications() {
    var tbl = $('#notification-panel');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Group/GetNotifications',
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Notification Hub

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        private static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPContext"].ToString();

        [HubMethodName("sendNotification")]
        public static void SendNotification()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateNotifications();
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPContext"].ConnectionString;
        public IEnumerable<scNotification> GetAllNotification(string userId)
        {
            var notifications = new List<scNotification>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                //var query = _dbContext.scNotifications.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.IsDeleted == false) as DbQuery<scNotification>;

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id], 
                [Title], [Description], [Url], [IsRead], [IsDeleted], [Date] FROM [dbo].[scNotification] WHERE userId = '" + userId + "'", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        notifications.Add(item: new scNotification
                        {
                            Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                            Title = (string)reader["Title"],
                            Description = reader["Description"] != DBNull.Value ?
                        (string)reader["Description"] : "",
                            Url = (string)reader["Url"],
                            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]),
                            IsRead = (bool)reader["IsRead"],
                            IsDeleted = (bool)reader["IsDeleted"]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return notifications;
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                NotificationHub.SendNotification();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible the tab you are opening is just a partial page or has a different _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: When you actually view the source of the new tab page - does it have the SignalR .js libraries referenced in code?

Comment: @Steve yes actually i have partial view to display notifications and use this partial view in _Layout.cshtml so can you please help me what i can do to resolve this problem???

Comment: ohhh @Steve thank you for your replay i resolve my problem after understanding your comment as per your comment i use ~/singlar/hubs and singalr.js in main layout.cshtml and remove it from partial view thank you again.